# C++ ifstream will read some values then stop

Tags: c++, binary, hex, fstream

I am trying to write a program that reads 940 4-byte long values of binary data [hex] from a bin file, and output the values to console. I have ifstream::read, cout and seekg operations in a loop.

It will work for the first 10 or so iterations, and then in one iteration skip the read and write operations, preform the seekg operation, and continue on reading and writing. Also the last 200 lines or so are coming out the same value.

It will work properly for 12 iterations, then it will start outputting the wrong numbers. At this point it goes from address 0x230 to 0x28B when it should be at 0x260. It looks like read and cout are not called in this particular iteration.

The last correct value reads 3f4fc938. The next value should be 3ef646c1.

Does anyone know why this would fail? Any help is appreciated.

This is the program:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    fstream in;
    uint32_t buffer;
    in.open(argv[1]);
    in.seekg(0x6500,in.beg);
    for(int i = 0; i < 940; i++) {
        in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&buffer),4);
        cout << hex << buffer << endl;
        in.seekg(0x2c,in.cur);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the state of `in` after each read?  Beyond that, there's not too much that anyone can do to help you debug this problem without an example input file.

Comment: At very least, you should check stream state after each read/seek. Unchanged values? This is the behaviour according to [pre-C++11 on error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Comment: in.fail() starts to return true while the values stop changing, but not during the rest of the loop where values are missing.

Comment: @Kasper Then something went wrong in your stream. Maybe an address beyond file length? If you don't clear the fail bit, then you won't be reading anything meaningful ever any more. I doubt, though, that just clearing the fail bit is a too good idea, especially on files. Probably stopping and rejecting the entire file as invalid is the better approach.

Comment: You are reading 32 bits but then using seek to jump forward 0x2c = 44 bits, so skipping an extra 12 bits each loop. Is your file format structured so that 0x6500 is guaranteed to be present and followed by 940 * (32bit + 12 bit) values?

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't think I'm going beyond the end of the file, the file is 0xc25cf bytes long. And the first problem I encounter is a while before the fail bit is even set. The read and cout skip, but then the file location skips ahead by 0x2c bytes with seekg, putting every address thereafter off.

Comment: @Daniels The data is structured in 0x30 byte long blocks. There are 940 of them. I need to read one float from each, which is at 0x20 bytes. So I start at the value, read 4 bytes, then skip ahead 2c bytes to the next value.

Comment: *'first problem I encounter is a while before the fail bit is even set'* - then you should describe more in detail what this problem is.

Comment: It will work properly for 12 iterations, then it will start outputting the wrong numbers. At this point it goes from address 0x230 to 0x28B when it should be at 0x260. It looks like read and cout are not called in this particular iteration. I don't know why this would happen or what other details you would need.

Comment: How did you find out about these addresses?

Comment: Without knowing your exact file format and expected interpretation it is not really possible to assist. I have run your code over a saved copy of https://www.gutenberg.org/files/58444/58444-0.txt and it iterates 939 times and outputs one line per iteration, so code appears to work as advertised for a random input.

Comment: Tip: C++ doesn't randomly "skip" commands. When debugging problems like this, you can focus on determining why it read something different from what you expected, rather than getting stuck on the notion that C++ "skips" commands (particularly your `cout`, which should have been treated as the _de facto_ authority on when a fresh loop iteration was being executed, rather than with such suspicion!). I see that a lot here and it's a bit weird. When in doubt, fire up your debugger and step through the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have opened your file in text mode. Text mode means that operations on the file will interpret a Byte sequence that matches the platform-specific representation of a newline as a single `'\n'` character. If you're on Windows, for example, newlines are represented as the Byte sequence `0D 0A`. So on Windows, whatever you do in your file will work well up to the point where your file happens to have a Byte with value 13 followed by a Byte with value 10. Once you reach that point, that 13 followed by 10 will be interpreted as a single character. Essentially, text mode will just swallow any Byte with value 13 if it happens to appear right before a Byte with value 10. Your application will never see the 13 and anything beyond the point where the 13 appeared will end up "shifted" by one Byte. On other platforms, other newline representations are common. If you wanna work with binary data, you will generally want to open your file in binary mode, for example

```
fstream in(argv[1], std::ios::binary);
```

or

```
in.open(argv[1], std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: I changed one line:
    in.open(argv[1], fstream::in | fstream::binary);
Everything works fine now. Thank you guys